# Session table size too big in joomla 2.5

Tags: database, joomla2.5

I have one news site using joomla 2.5. Yesterday I noticed the database size. It is over 800 MB. Then I checked the database, and I found one table (session table) is really big in size. I searched for a solution via Google and found that Joomla will create & destroy sessions  automatically. I changed the session handler to 'none', but joomla is still creating sessions in the database. It is not deleting records from session table automatically. This size of the database is increasing day by day. How can I fix that?

Comment: strange, entries should be removed automatically. you can empty the table yourself, though users logged at the moment will be logged out. or you can remove all entries except the last xx

Comment: yes.. I can but why joomla didn't automatically delete these records. I think somethings wrong ! And foreign keys will dismiss !

Comment: i have no idea why, since i never encountered such issue. can you check what is set for the session time in global configuration?

Comment: This happened to me too, I resorted to a cron job cleaning up yesterday's sessions, and I had to disable sessions in the frontend for non-logged-in users (if I recall correctly with a core hack).

Comment: just check if using db storage for session check the column's data type and length